# How can I restore the Ubuntu boot manager?

Tags: windows-8-preview, multi-boot, ubuntu-12.04

First I had Windows 7, Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04 installed side by side as triple boot.

Ubuntu Boot Manager was the primary one. Then I deleted the Windows 8 part and upgraded my Windows 7 to Windows 8.

Now when I boot in my system, I don't get the Ubuntu boot manager at all and directly boot into Windows 8.

Moreover, the partitions of Ubuntu were of ext4 format, so I can't even access those. And to top it all, now when I make a flashable Ubuntu in a pendrive and try to boot from it, it says no OS found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/forums/showthread.php?t=642) (beta required to work with the win 8 bootloader). Once you boot into windows 8, it can find the partitions (if they still exist) and then add them to the boot loader.

Go to the add new entry tab:

[image]

Then go to the tab the describes what OS what you want to use (if you want to add ubuntu, go to the linux tab for example) and then select the partition that has the OS (or let it find it automatically, but I have no experience with that).

[image]

This will make the default bootloader windows 8, but you can change this if you use a grub disk or similar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can you please be a bit more detailed?I downloaded and installed EasyBCD. After that?

Comment: See edits, I added some more instructions and pictures

Comment: I figured it out before I saw this. But thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [RescaTux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/). This one is a LiveCD distro for (re)installing, updating, configuring and repairing GRUB.